# A few reps still there after recreating a deleted account

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reputation

It's a little bug I have noticed for some time: I deleted my SO account long ago, and I believe I deleted it more than one time. However, each time I recreate it, I get the usual 101 reps, and an additional 50 reps.

I just discovered where they come from, by looking at the time plot: apparently I get 50 reps from my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18679525/top-20-of-the-people-earn-80-of-the-money-this-type-of-result-using-r), even though it's deleted, and should have been anonymized after account deletion. There, *user1220978* was my account at the time the answer was written, and I'm not entirely sure about *user6015398* who deleted the answer, but it may be another me.

Now, I don't really mind having those extra reps, but I feel there may be a bug somewhere in the system.

Comment: The answer is yours and it was visible for more then 6 months and I believe that makes that you keep the rep. That whole Q/A was migrated from stats.se so maybe also migration logic is at play here. I wouldn't worry too much about it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When you create a new account, any posts you created on another site but which has been migrated to Stack Overflow is automatically associated with that new account. See the [central FAQ on migration](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10249/what-is-migration-and-how-does-it-work):

> If [anyone who participated in the question on the origin site (asked it, answered it, or edited or commented on it or any of its answers)] later create an account on the destination site, their username will be linked to their new account on posts and edits[.]

That’s how that specific answer gets attached to your account again. And while it may be deleted now, it wasn’t deleted until after the post had been on the site for more than 60 days *and* it had a score of 3 or higher, which means reputation earned for such a post is *not removed*.

See the [FAQ on post deletions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that):

> [R]eputation earned for posts with a score of 3 or higher, and where the post has been visible on the site for at least 60 days, is retained.

In other words: you earned the 50 points for that post, fair and square.

Comment: Thanks. An interesting and unexpected consequence of the first rule you quote. I wasn't aware of the other one, but it's less surprising. So migrated posts are never really unlinked. Another possibility would have been to link on account creation and unlink forever on the next account deletion, but it's not what was chosen. Good to know.